# Sharepoint function to replace multiple characters

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

is there any function that can delete or erase all numbers in a single column?

example: i want to erase all zeros(0)

January0
0February
0March
April0
wo0rd

and results should be:

January
February
March
April
word

Comment: Do they really need to be deleted from the Field Value, or are you fine when only in the View display they are replaced?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you need

#### Replace characters in the View or Form  (SP2013/SP2016/SPO)

This can easily be done with CSR (Client Side Rendering)

- User the [Cisar WYSIWYG CSR editor](http://365csi.nl/cisar)
- one simple function for use on Views/Forms

  ```
  var fieldvalue=ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
  return fieldvalue.replace(/0/g,'');
  ```

#### Replace characters in value (Calculated Column) (SP2003 - SPO)

SharePoint has no `SUBSTITUTE` function, and the `REPLACE` function only replaces ONE string instance

So all you can do is nest FIND & REPLACE ***and merge them into one Formula***

[image]

(so Output_1 to Ouput_6 are not required)

Output_7:

`=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,"")),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,"")),1,"")),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,"")),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,"")),1,"")),1,"")),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,"")),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,"")),1,"")),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,"")),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,""),FIND("0",REPLACE(Input,FIND("0",Input),1,"")),1,"")),1,"")),1,"")),1,"")`

**Alas** SharePoint can only nest 7 levels, so you can't merge Output_7 into Output_8

Output_8 needs to start from Output_7 Calculated Column (*replace `Input` with `Output_7` in the above Formula*)

#### Hacky alternative, replace in View only

#### using JavaScript in a Calculated Column (SP2013,16,SPO - except Modern Experiences)

Provided you only need this in a **View** and can live with the (minor) [sideeffects](http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How)

You create **only one Calculated Column**, set to output as Number with the Formula:

```
="<img src=/_layouts/images/blank.gif onload=""{"
 &"var TD=this.parentNode.parentNode;"
 &"TD.innerHTML='" & Col &"'.replace(/0/g,'');"
&"}"">"
```

This will rework **Col** every time it is displayed in a View, so you can't use the "Calculation" anywhere else.

Explanation and why JavaScript in a Calculated Column (in a VIEW!) works is here:http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

This is easier implemented than CSR, but CSR can do it for you on Forms as well.