# SharePoint calculated column replace all spaces

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, json-formatting

This is my requirement:

Here, I have taken a single line of text column with 2 spaces in the column field. I have used that column as a reference in a calculated column. By using a formula I can able to replace the first space but I can not able to replace all the remaining spaces. I want every space to fill at the same time. what will happen if I take a column with 4-5 spaces. how to replace all spaces? Is there any way to do it?

Formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",[ Employee Contact number])),REPLACE([ Employee Contact number],FIND(" ",[ Employee Contact number]),1," -"),[ Employee Contact number])
```

[image]

Comment: Do you just want to show the replaced number in list view (for display purpose) or are you going to use it somewhere else in your project (like filtering/sorting list views, power apps, power automate or anything else)?

Comment: I want to replace every space with a hyphen in the mobile number column. If we want to replace the second space we should have to create another calculated column taking the mobile number column as a reference. Instead of that, I want to replace every space using single formula at a time.is it possible ?

Comment: I understood your requirements from your question. But I want to know how you are going the calculated column values in future? Will those be used for list view filtering/sorting or in integration with any other services as mentioned in my above comment?

Comment: I want it for displaying purpose in a list view.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time and solution

Comment: Hi @Chandrika, is below solution working for you? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (by clicking the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no function available in SharePoint calculated column formulas which will replace all spaces from column value automatically.

SharePoint calculated column formulas supports `REPLACE` function which replaces only one instance of the space character at a time.

So, if you want to replace multiple space characters, you will have to replicate the same REPLACE function logic for all spaces.

You can find some similar questions for more information at:

1. [Calculated Column Formula how to replace Substitute](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149491/calculated-column-formula-how-to-replace-substitute)
2. [Sharepoint function to replace multiple characters](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214026/sharepoint-function-to-replace-multiple-characters)
3. [replace text with formula in calculate](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93770/replace-text-with-formula-in-calculate)

---

**Additional**:

If you just want the replaced mobile number for display purpose in SharePoint list view only, you can use JSON formatting for your requirements.

1. Create a calculate column using simple formula like: `="Mobile Number"`
2. Then apply JSON column formatting to your calculated column and use below JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=replaceAll([$ContactNumber], ' ', '-')",
  "style": {
    "font-weight": "bold"
  }
}
```

Where `ContactNumber` is the **internal name** of column with spaces in it. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Follow the steps given here to apply JSON column formatting: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

**Output**:

[image]

**Reference**: [SharePoint: Replace All Occurrences of Substring in a String using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/08/22/sharepoint-replace-all-occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string-using-json-formatting/)